# func(*tuple) 'scatters' tuples, but how does func(**dictionary) work?

Tags: python, dictionary, args, keyword-argument

Let's create a simple tuple, dictionary and function.

```
>>> tup = (7, 3)
>>> dic = {"kw1":7, "kw2":3}
>>> def pr(a, b):
...    print a, b
```

The following shows what `*` does before a tuple and dictionary as an argument.

```
>>> pr(tup)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: pr() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

>>> pr(*tup)  
7 3   

>>> pr(*dic)
kw1 kw2
```

Now let's try `**` before an argument.

```
>>> pr(**tup)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: pr() argument after ** must be a mapping, not tuple
```

Ok, it seems ** only works when a dictionary is used as an argument. So let's try it with a dictionary then.

```
>>> pr(**dic)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: pr() got an unexpected keyword argument 'kw1'
```

What? 
Can anybody show me an example of this last case that doesn't produce an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `pr` function takes arguments `a` and `b`, not `kw1` and `kw2`.

```
>>> def pr(a, b):
...   print a, b
... 
>>> 
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b':2}
>>> pr(**d)
1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to the other answers, you can use `*args` and `**kwargs` to your function definition to support arbitrary arguments. This may make the code less explicit. But for debug purposes, flexibility and development speed this may make sense to adopt:

(The `*`/`**`-notation in the function definition is like the "inverse" operation to the argument unpacking operation on function call.)

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs): 
    for v in args: 
        print v
    for v in kwargs: 
        print v, "->", kwargs[v]

dic = {"kw1":7, "kw2":3}

foo(dic)
# prints:
# {'kw1': 7, 'kw2': 3}

foo(**dic)
# prints:
# kw1 -> 7
# kw2 -> 3
```

---

some related links to the documentation:

- http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-keyword-argument
- http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-argument
- http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-on-defining-functions

  - http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments
  - http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although your answer is helpful I ticked Daniel's answer for its brevity and because he was first.

Comment: @Bentley4 - absolutely, especially as my answer doesn't directly answer your question, but attempts to give some additional information.

Answer (score 2):

The `**dict` notation means that your dictionary is turned into keyword arguments. If the function doesn't possess the necessary keyword, then it will return an error, as you experienced.

In your case, it *would* work if you defined your function as follows:

```
>>> def pr(kw1, kw2):
...    print kw1, kw2
```

Comment: You and Daniel both answer the question but in a different manner, if I could tick both answers as the correct one I would.

Comment: I tossed a coin and Daniel won. Forgive me.